# Property of lower central series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I would like some help to understand the following property of lower central series of groups and commutators.
A little bit of context and notation: $G$ is a group, $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are elements of $\gamma_{i}(G)$, which is the $i$-th element of the lower central series, $g_{1}$ e $g_{2}$ elements of $G$ such that $x_{1}\gamma_{i+1}(G)= x_{2}\gamma_{i+1}(G)$ and $g_{1}G' = g_{2}G'$, where $G'$ is the commutator subgroup. Then my book proceeds to observe that the cosets $[x_{2}, g_{1}]\gamma_{i+2}(G)$ e $[x_{2}, g_{2}]\gamma_{i+2}(G)$ belong to the centre of the quotient group $G/\gamma_{i+2}(G)$. Why is that true? I'm sure I'm missing something very trivial and boring, but I'm having trouble with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the point is the following:

Suppose that $x \in \gamma_{i}(G)$ and $g \in G$. Then by definition of $\gamma_{i+1}(G) = [\gamma_i(G),G]$, we know that the commutator $[x,g]$ is an element of $\gamma_{i+1}(G)$.

Let $h \gamma_{i+2}(G)$ be an arbitrary coset in $G/\gamma_{i+2}(G)$.

Since $[x,g]h[x,g]^{-1}h^{-1} = [[x,g],h] \in \gamma_{i+2}(G)$, we know that

$\left(([x,g]h)\gamma_{i+2}(G)\right) \left( [x,g]^{-1}h^{-1} \right)\gamma_{i+2}(G) = \left( [x,g]h[x,g]^{-1}h^{-1} \right) \gamma_{i+2}(G) = \gamma_{i+2}(G)$

and so

$\left(([x,g]h)\gamma_{i+2}(G)\right) = \left((h[x,g])\gamma_{i+2}(G)\right)$,

which shows that $[x,g]\gamma_{i+2}(G)$ belongs to the centre of $G/\gamma_{i+2}(G)$.